# What does "hoppers" and "beat of the street" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *John Wick Chapter 4* (2023), DJ reported that Marquis has put a 26 million dollar bounty on John Wick's head.

> D J: All right, now. For all you **hoppers** out there in the City of
> Lights, for all  you street people with an ear for the action, to all
> my loyal listeners who know - the **beat of the street**...-(TURNS UP
> RADIO) ...tonight is your chance to make some  beautiful music. I've
> been asked to relay a special request from a secret admirer. It seems
> there's a thorn in our little slice of paradise.

What does "hoppers" and "beat of the street" mean ?

Comment: [1] hopper == young street-level drug dealer == gang member [2] beat of the street == heart beat of the street == pulse of the street == what is going on recently in the streets [3] Basically , asking the gang members ( who should know who the target is ) to attack that target !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hopper" is American urban slang for a street-level drug dealer.

"Beat" is slang for music, so "the beat of the street" means "the music of the streets". In this context, it also refers to "how the streets work". So, it's calling on street-level people to use their street know-how to find John Wick and earn the bounty.

Comment: "the music of the streets".? Context is **bounty** not **music**.

Comment: @CameronMelvin I've added some to my answer.